# Fiware multitenancy

Tags: fiware, fiware-orion, fiware-wilma

We are evaluating several platforms for integrating a "Smart Energy System".
One important requirement we have to support is multitenancy. From the docs I can see the possibility to start the Orion Context Broker with this option. Orion will ensure the data separation based on the `fiware-service` request header.
That's fine but how to "secure" this header across the whole software stack (PEP-Proxy, IoT-Agent)?
Which component/device sets this header? Which component ensures that a request with a specific `fiware-service` header value is authorized to access the data of this tenant?

In my opinion this is a task for Wilma as PEP-Proxy. All traffic to Orion is routed through the PEP-Proxy and the proxy checks if this request is valid. Unfortunately I can not find such a check within the source code nor it is explained in the documentation.
Has someone implemented such an architecture an can help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found another post which answers my question

> [How to configure access control in Orion NGSI API for tenant isolation using Wilma PEP Proxy and IdM Keyrock?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44834629/how-to-configure-access-control-in-orion-ngsi-api-for-tenant-isolation-using-wil?rq=1)

We will have to implement this kind of authorization for our own.